# Migrating Users from Springboot to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, spring-boot, encryption

We are swapping our Backend from Java Springboot to C# ASP.NET.

Springboot seems to use a different type of encryption for password hashing than ASP.

Springboot `$2a$10$AxIQRdy2pmdXHBotzu3g0OOCAoaBZFvDaFmlSqlsChPhrCoCAmLKy`

ASP `AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEJ9QPriBB1QkTaSgRZQBe7mDb+ILWYWHChdjPHbLpfsFjSmpnkI4x2G+aexg0JL01A==`

My approach would be to overwrite the UserManager in ASP.NET Identity to use a different encryption, but would appreciate someone to help me out here.

EDIT: Also, ASP.NET Identity has a SecurityStamp column for Users. How would I generate those

Comment: Looks like there are a number of different options in springboot. You'll first need to check your code to work out which is being used https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt

Answer (score 0):

After looking more into this whole Password Hashing topic, I found a pretty simple solution for my problem.

My Springboot Backend was using BCrypt for password hashing. With the help of the Nuget Package **BCrypt.Net-Next** I was able to verify those hashes once a User signed in and if it was succesfull, just create a new Hash using ASP. Identity. I added this code to my Authenticate function:

```
if (user.PasswordHash.StartsWith("$2a"))
        {
            var bcryptResult = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(request.Password, user.PasswordHash);
            if(!bcryptResult)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Credentials for '{request.Email} aren't valid'.");
            }

            var newHash = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, request.Password);
            user.PasswordHash = newHash;
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        }
```